# Youtube Data API V3 returning ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) error even though it was working before

Tags: python, ssl, youtube-data-api

I am trying to write a bot that uploads videos for me and I have already got it working and uploaded a few videos with it. Suddenly it appears to have stopped working though and now just returns the following error:

ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2408)

I do not understand where this comes from and why, the internet was of no help and I tried to read the file where it came from but am no smarter from doing that.

This is my code that tries to upload a video:

```
def upload(beatName, mainArtist, keywords, oneLiner):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_file.json'
    API_NAME = 'youtube'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']

    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

    upload_date_time = DT.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 12, 30, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'

    title = "xxx"
    description = 'xxx'

    request_body = {
        'snippet': {
            'categoryI': 10,
            'title': title,
            'description': description,
            'tags': keywords
        },
        'status': {
            'privacyStatus': 'private',
            'publishAt': upload_date_time,
            'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False,
        },
        'notifySubscribers': True
    }

    mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('E:\Everything.mp4')

    response_upload = service.videos().insert(
        part = 'snippet,status',
        body = request_body,
        media_body = mediaFile
    ).execute()
```

What could be the cause of the error and how can I approach trying to find a solution?

EDIT:

After updating my client as a commenter suggested (which was indeed one version too old) I am now getting a different error instead, which I also am unable to deal with:

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.UnsupportedGrantTypeError: (unsupported_grant_type) Invalid grant_type: 

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/ricsi/Desktop/Automatic Beat Uploader/main.py", line 34, in <module>
     AutomaticUploader().run()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1402, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1418, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Desktop\Automatic Beat Uploader\automaticuploader.kv", line 53, in <module>
     on_press: root.upload()
   File "C:/Users/ricsi/Desktop/Automatic Beat Uploader/main.py", line 27, in upload
     upload(beatName, mainArtist, keywords, oneLiner)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Desktop\Automatic Beat Uploader\youtube.py", line 144, in upload
     service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Desktop\Automatic Beat Uploader\Google.py", line 31, in Create_Service
     cred = flow.run_local_server()
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 460, in run_local_server
     self.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 281, in fetch_token
     self.client_config['token_uri'], **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 360, in fetch_token
     self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 421, in parse_request_body_response
     self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 431, in parse_token_response
     validate_token_parameters(params)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 438, in validate_token_parameters
     raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
   File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\errors.py", line 405, in raise_from_error
     raise cls(**kwargs)
 oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.UnsupportedGrantTypeError: (unsupported_grant_type) Invalid grant_type:
```

Adding the debug log, per request(sensitive data has been changed):

```
INFO:google_auth_oauthlib.flow:"GET /?state=J4aIHazfWta0WBvU5X5mtHzb6Xh1hT&code=4/3gGqpfkFDfV9nVgE4PkISwAB0pgFkD9-CcukEOhLk_FMxvsj0Ca9CBSpEvBpU0nzN63gbjeP2_WkfMaTgRa3gnA&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload HTTP/1.1" 200 65
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Encoding `client_id` "36097-31saf6e4sdfDAG3amuivcki8vgo3rmfgj.apps.googleusercontent.com" with `client_secret` as Basic auth credentials.
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Requesting url https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token using method POST.
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Supplying headers {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'} and data {'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': '4/3gGqpfkFDfV9nVgE4PkISwAB0pgFkD9-CcukEOhLk_FMxvsj0Ca9CBSpEvBpU0nzN63gbjeP2_WkfMaTgRa3gnA', 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/'}
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Passing through key word arguments {'timeout': None, 'auth': <requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth object at 0x000001CD14ECFAC8>, 'verify': True, 'proxies': None}.
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443

DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 400 None
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Request to fetch token completed with status 400.
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Request url was https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Request headers were {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '172', 'Authorization': 'Basic NjY0NdfwDE0ODEyLXRtbnE0dGddfgEx4azZndTNq3dDU2c3Nodm45tLmGRFwcHMuZ29456FGertxldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29df3Q3E1VXpRDRpNDFqUTlfeTY5bw=='}
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Request body was grant_type=authorization_code&code=4%2F3gEwdk40hc5ItuvD-JBsg4fdjKsx534dhf7df5KtdGhxIGS5646gh56K61-tW5cxOz34tG6Sg8Adysic3u12I346StHbT9Y4564Shg&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Response headers were {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Date': 'Thu, 27 Aug 2020 22:08:18 GMT', 'Server': 'scaffolding on HTTPServer2', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'} and content {
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}.
DEBUG:requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session:Invoking 0 token response hooks.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Desktop\Automatic Beat Uploader\Google.py", line 31, in Create_Service
    cred = flow.run_local_server()
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 460, in run_local_server
    self.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 281, in fetch_token
    self.client_config['token_uri'], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 360, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 421, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 431, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 438, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
  File "C:\Users\ricsi\Anaconda3\envs\Automatic Beat Uploader\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\errors.py", line 405, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.UnsupportedGrantTypeError: (unsupported_grant_type) Invalid grant_type:
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63612637/edit) your post, adding to it a full exception stack trace (as text!). Also make sure you have installed the latest version of Google's APIs Client Library for Python; see the current version with `pip show google-api-python-client`; then if it's not [the newest](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/releases), `pip install --update google-api-python-client`.

Comment: I would but another error has now taken the place of this one (without me changing ANYTHING) so I am now unable to replicate it.. google's apis are quite a pain

Comment: In any case, update your client library.

Comment: Yup I did that, that’s when the new error popped up (i guess I did change something after all)

Comment: Then post that error's full stack trace. (Here on SO is no issue if one just edits his/her original post.)

Comment: @stvar okay, did that!

Comment: @stvar hm, I read that post and tried checking the google api client version at runtime, it showed to be the newest. I shouldn't have old versions of anything since I have been building this project for only 4-5 days. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Try renaming the pickle file; then rerun the authorization flow for to obtain a new one.

Comment: Add `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` (needs an import `import logging` too) before the call to `Create_Service`. This is for to see the authorization response as logged within the function [`OAuth2Session.fetch_token`](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/46f886ccb74652fc9c850ece960edcf2bce765a5/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py#L353). Then post that log text, carefully editing out credentials data.

Comment: @stvar I already deleted the pickle file, hoping that creating a new one would solve the problem, the authorization flow doesn't create a new one though, possibly because it fails and throws an error. I added the full error log with logging on to the end of my post.

Comment: Does your `Request body` log line *contain* the `client_id=...` and `client_secret=...` parameters -- and these *match exactly* the values in your client secret JSON file? Does your `redirect_uri` parameter (`http://localhost:8080/`) *match exactly* the value entered on [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)?

Comment: I suspect that the request headers shouldn't contain the header `Authorization: Basic ...` at all. That may confuse the server. I'll have to look for it further.

Comment: I suggest to check and update the [google-auth-oauthlib](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/releases), [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests/releases) and [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/releases) packages too.

Comment: Also make sure -- by checking the version numbers at run-time -- that your script runs indeed the packages you just updated.

Comment: I checked and all the libraries are up to date. But weirdly, my request body does not contain the clien_secret or the client_id paramaters, as you can also see in the error log that I added to the end of my post, I didn't delete anything from there.   @stvar

Comment: Then look into `client_secret_file.json` and see if it is of [proper format](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_client_secrets) and contains valid values.

Comment: I can confirm that your `Create_Service` functions OK: I managed to obtain a valid pickle file upon a successful OAuth  flow.  See my client secret JSON file in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50332824#50332824).

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: this is not an answer, only an attempt at tackling the OP's issue.)

Please have the following derived class defined in your source file:

```py
class InstalledAppFlow2(InstalledAppFlow):

    def fetch_token(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("client_secret", self.client_config["client_secret"])
        kwargs.setdefault("code_verifier", self.code_verifier)
        return self.oauth2session.fetch_token(
            self.client_config["token_uri"],
            include_client_id = True,
            **kwargs)
```

Then replace

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
```

with

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow2.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
```

The purpose of `InstalledAppFlow2` is to make the `flow` object pass on to the function [`OAuth2Session.fetch_token`](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/46f886ccb74652fc9c850ece960edcf2bce765a5/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py#L175) the parameter `include_client_id = True`; this parameter will indicate to `OAuth2Session.fetch_token` to have `client_id` and `client_secret` passed on within the request body of the authorization call made to the server.

Then verify again the log file produced for its line `Request body` to have `client_id=...` and `client_secret=...`. Also the `Request header` line should no more have `Authorization: Basic ...`.

Comment: I did that, the log file request body now has client id and client secret and the header no longer has authorization basic, yet the same error still persists.. I also double checked the client secret json file, but it appears to be right. I downloaded it straight from google cloud console and haven't tinkered with it at all, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with it.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Try to play a bit with Google's [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). See whether I can pass the step no. 2, `Exchange authorization code for tokens`. Note that the right side of that page presents the entire request and response texts.

Comment: by trying to authorize youtube data api v3 by using my own oauth credentials the playground gives me Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Comment: Click the `OAuth 2.0 Configuration` button, the click the checkbox `Use your own OAuth credentials`, the enter your own credentials (client ID and secret).

Comment: yup i did that, also used the same scope that i'm trying to use in my code, yet i get redirect uri mismatch

Comment: The redirect uri mismatch seems to be correct, since you configured within the console the redirect uri to be `http://localhost:8080/`; yet the playground page sets that to something like `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground`.

Comment: yes it does say within the playground that i have to add that uri to the allowed uri's list, yet I can't seem to find such a list anywhere, and I didn't configure that localhost uri myself, it was done automatically when I downloaded the client secret file..

Comment: That list is in fact an JSON array within your client secret JSON file under the key name `"redirect_uri"`.

Comment: okay, I configured the redirect uri and went back to oauth playground, i did manage to pass step two without issues and got access and refresh tokens back (showing on the right side of the screen)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220627/discussion-between-stvar-and-justadudetryingtocode).